# Get log statements lower than WARN do display in spark-submit script

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging

I have a python entry point, `test_logging.py`, that I submit to spark in cluster mode. It  looks like:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
with SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() as spark:
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")
    logger.debug("Debug")
    logger.info("Info")
    logger.warning("Warning")
```

The spark-submit invocation looks like this:

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-submit
    --conf
    spark.app.name=my-app
    --conf
    spark.driver.cores=8
    --conf
    spark.driver.memory=2g
    --conf
    spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
    --conf
    spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=10
    --conf
    spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=20
    --conf
    spark.executor.cores=8
    --conf
    spark.executor.instances=20
    --conf
    spark.executor.memory=8g
    --conf
    spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=8g
    --conf
    spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
    --conf
    spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    --conf
    spark.home={some_dir}/spark2-client
    --conf
    spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive
    --conf
    spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0
    --conf
    spark.master=yarn
    --conf
    spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
    --conf
    spark.files={some_dir}/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml
    test_logging.py
```

The issue is that only the final log statement, the warning, shows up in the spark stdout logs. My understanding [from here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15344) was that the line `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")` should have allowed debug-level statements and up to appear, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I make the debug-level and info-level log statements show up as well?

**Update**

Turns out that one can make those debug and info log statements appear by setting the following:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I'm still not completely sure why modifying the root logger's level  works whereas what I had originally tried doesn't work. I also don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Any explanations are much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of script, please try to set it on the cluster using manager which ever distribution you are using.

Comment: I don't have permissions to do that, so I can only do this via the script/submit args.